# Wiring diagram for Arduino to prevent relay firing on reboot

Tags: relay

I'm starting to explore using an Arduino to control a couple of switches programatically. I have read somewhere about relays firing during reboot due to floating inputs/outputs during the reboot phase.

What is the best way to ensure that a relay will not fire on a reboot?

Is there a simple wiring diagram to explain it? I am using an Arduino Uno and a [Relay Module](https://www.jaycar.com.au/medias/sys_master/images/8978832654366/XC4419-dataSheetMain.pdf).

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. If that relay uses a FET input with no pulldown then you should add your own. If it uses an opto-isolator there is no floating problem to deal with.
2. Don't use pin 13 for a relay - that is connected to the LED which blinks during reset and will "flash" your relay.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a pull down/up resistor between the wire and ground/vcc so that when the arduino pin is set to high impedance during reboot the wire is pulled low/high as desired.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the best way to ensure that a relay will not fire on a reboot?

put pull-up/down, as appropriate, on those pins.